# ithit ajaxbrowser prompting for NPAPI plugin on non-office documents when using chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We are using the latest ajaxbrowser that can now open office type documents without the soon to be unsupported npapi plug-in.   We are however still seeing the issue with other file types.  Is there a way to open other files without seeing the error message in chrome or is this being fixed soon?

Answer (score 1):

I see that currently the best solution is to use other web browser to open non-MS Office documents via IT Hit NPAPI plugin.

I see that enabling NPAPI in Chrome is a temporary solution. According to Google after the release of Chrome version 45, we will have to use an alternatively web browser to load content that requires a NPAPI plugin ( https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en ).

Do you plan to create new IT Hit plugin (PPAPI) for Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

To open non-MS Office documents you will need the Java applet. The Java applets use NPAPI that are disabled in Google Chrome by default. The only solution is to use other web browsers or enable NPAPI in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed since v1.9.1.1408
http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/download/release_history/